# Count Comparisons in BubbleSort, QuickSort

Tags: java, big-o

I am trying to correctly count the number of comparisons of each algorithm, but i do not think i am putting my counters in the correct places.

SortsMain is the test client.

```
public class SortsMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random ranNum = new Random();

    System.out.println("Enter size of Array: ");
    int sizeOfArray = scan.nextInt();

    Comparable array[] = new Comparable[sizeOfArray];

    System.out.println("Size of Array is: " + sizeOfArray);

    System.out.println("Unsorted array: ");
    for (int a = 0; a < sizeOfArray; a++) {
        array[a] = ranNum.nextInt(2147483647);
        System.out.print(array[a] + ", ");
    }

    System.out.println("Press 1 to use Bubble Sort");
    System.out.println("Press 2 to use Quick Sort");

    int typeOfSortChoice = scan.nextInt();

    //bubble sort
    if (typeOfSortChoice == 1) {
        SortsClass.bubbleSort(array, sizeOfArray);
        //6 numbers = 15 comparisons (5+4+3+2+1)
        //comparisons = (n*(n-1)/2)
    }

    //quick sort
    if (typeOfSortChoice == 2) {
        SortsClass.quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    }      
    /*for (int a = 0; a < sizeOfArray; a++){
        System.out.println(array[a]);
    }*/

    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array) + '\n');

    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

SortsClass contains the bubble sort and quick sort methods.

```
    // The file contains 5 static methods for sorting arrays of Comparable items
    // It will compile with warnings about unchecked exceptions

public class SortsClass {

    static int comparisonCounter = 0;
    static int comparisonCounter2 = 0;


    //Comparable[] theArray = new Comparable[theArray.length];

    public static void selectionSort(Comparable[] theArray, int n)
    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // Sorts the items in an array into ascending order.
    // Precondition: theArray is an array of n items.
    // Postcondition: theArray is sorted into
    // ascending order.
    // Calls: indexOfLargest.
    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // last = index of the last item in the subarray of
    // items yet to be sorted
    // largest = index of the largest item found
    {
        for (int last = n - 1; last >= 1; last--) {
            // Invariant: theArray[last+1..n-1] is sorted
            // and > theArray[0..last]
            // select largest item in theArray[0..last]
            int largest = indexOfLargest(theArray, last + 1);
            // swap largest item theArray[largest] with
            // theArray[last]
            Comparable temp = theArray[largest];
            theArray[largest] = theArray[last];
            theArray[last] = temp;
        } // end for
    } // end selectionSort

    /*******************************************************************************/
    private static int indexOfLargest(Comparable[] theArray, int size)
    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // Finds the largest item in an array.
    // Precondition: theArray is an array of size items;
    // size >= 1.
    // Postcondition: Returns the index of the largest
    // item in the array.
    // ---------------------------------------------------
    {
        int indexSoFar = 0; // index of largest item found so far
        // Invariant: theArray[indexSoFar]>=theArray[0..currIndex-1]
        for (int currIndex = 1; currIndex < size; ++currIndex) {
            if (theArray[currIndex].compareTo(theArray[indexSoFar]) > 0) {
                indexSoFar = currIndex;
            } // end if
        } // end for
        return indexSoFar; // index of largest item
    } // end indexOfLargest

    /*************************
     * Dumb Bubble
     ********************************/
    public static void bubbleSort(Comparable[] theArray, int n)
    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // Sorts the items in an array into ascending order.
    // Precondition: theArray is an array of n items.
    // Postcondition: theArray is sorted into ascending
    // order.
    // ---------------------------------------------------
    {
        boolean sorted = false; // false when swaps occur
        for (int pass = 1; (pass < n) && !sorted; ++pass) {
            // Invariant: theArray[n+1-pass..n-1] is sorted
            // and > theArray[0..n-pass]

            sorted = true; // assume sorted

            for (int index = 0; index < n - pass; ++index) {
                comparisonCounter++;

                // Invariant: theArray[0..index-1] <= theArray[index]
                int nextIndex = index + 1;

                if (theArray[index].compareTo(theArray[nextIndex]) > 0) {

                    // exchange items
                    Comparable temp = theArray[index];
                    theArray[index] = theArray[nextIndex];
                    theArray[nextIndex] = temp;
                    sorted = false; // signal exchange


                } // end if
                //System.out.println(theArray[index]);
            } // end for

            // Assertion: theArray[0..n-pass-1] < theArray[n-pass]
        } // end for
        System.out.println("Number of Comparisons made: " + comparisonCounter);
        for (int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(theArray[i]);
        }
    } // end bubbleSort

    /*******************************************************************************/
    public static void insertionSort(Comparable[] theArray, int n)
    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // Sorts the items in an array into ascending order.
    // Precondition: theArray is an array of n items.
    // Postcondition: theArray is sorted into ascending
    // order.
    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // unsorted = first index of the unsorted region,
    // loc = index of insertion in the sorted region,
    // nextItem = next item in the unsorted region
    // initially, sorted region is theArray[0],
    // unsorted region is theArray[1..n-1];
    {
        for (int unsorted = 1; unsorted < n; ++unsorted) {
            // Invariant: theArray[0..unsorted-1] is sorted
            // find the right position (loc) in
            // theArray[0..unsorted] for theArray[unsorted],
            // which is the first item in the unsorted
            // region; shift, if necessary, to make room
            Comparable nextItem = theArray[unsorted];
            int loc = unsorted;
            while ((loc > 0) && (theArray[loc - 1].compareTo(nextItem) > 0)) {
                // shift theArray[loc-1] to the right
                theArray[loc] = theArray[loc - 1];
                loc--;
            } // end while
            // insert nextItem into sorted region
            theArray[loc] = nextItem;
        } // end for
    } // end insertionSort

    /**************************************************************************************/
    private static void merge(Comparable[] theArray, int first, int mid, int last)
    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    // Merges two sorted array segments theArray[first..mid] and
    // theArray[mid+1..last] into one sorted array.
    // Precondition: first <= mid <= last. The subarrays
    // theArray[first..mid] and theArray[mid+1..last] are
    // each sorted in increasing order.
    // Postcondition: theArray[first..last] is sorted.
    // Implementation note: This method merges the two
    // subarrays into a temporary array and copies the result
    // into the original array anArray.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    {
        int maxSize = theArray.length;
        // temporary array
        Comparable[] tempArray = new Comparable[maxSize];
        // initialize the local indexes to indicate the subarrays
        int first1 = first; // beginning of first subarray
        int last1 = mid; // end of first subarray
        int first2 = mid + 1; // beginning of second subarray
        int last2 = last; // end of second subarray
        // while both subarrays are not empty, copy the
        // smaller item into the temporary array
        int index = first1; // next available location in
        // tempArray
        while ((first1 <= last1) && (first2 <= last2)) {
            // Invariant: tempArray[first1..index-1] is in order
            if (theArray[first1].compareTo(theArray[first2]) < 0) {
                tempArray[index] = theArray[first1];
                first1++;
            } else {
                tempArray[index] = theArray[first2];
                first2++;
            } // end if
            index++;
        } // end while
        // finish off the nonempty subarray
        // finish off the first subarray, if necessary
        while (first1 <= last1) {
            // Invariant: tempArray[first1..index-1] is in order
            tempArray[index] = theArray[first1];
            first1++;
            index++;
        } // end while
        // finish off the second subarray, if necessary
        while (first2 <= last2) {
            // Invariant: tempArray[first1..index-1] is in order
            tempArray[index] = theArray[first2];
            first2++;
            index++;
        } // end while
        // copy the result back into the original array
        for (index = first; index <= last; ++index) {
            theArray[index] = tempArray[index];
        } // end for
    } // end merge

    /**************************************************************************/
    public static void mergesort(Comparable[] theArray, int first, int last)
    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    // Sorts the items in an array into ascending order.
    // Precondition: theArray[first..last] is an array.
    // Postcondition: theArray[first..last] is sorted in
    // ascending order.
    // Calls: merge.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    {
        if (first < last) {
            // sort each half
            int mid = (first + last) / 2; // index of midpoint
            // sort left half theArray[first..mid]
            mergesort(theArray, first, mid);
            // sort right half theArray[mid+1..last]
            mergesort(theArray, mid + 1, last);
            // merge the two halves
            merge(theArray, first, mid, last);
        } // end if
    } // end mergesort

    /*******************************************************************************/
    private static void choosePivot(Comparable[] theArray, int first, int last)
    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    // Chooses a pivot for quicksort's partition algorithm and
    // swaps it with the first item in an array.
    // Precondition: theArray[first..last] is an array;
    // first <= last.
    // Postcondition: theArray[first] is the pivot.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    {
        //Technically you don't have to do anything here. It's not
        // a great way to do it, but it will work! If you want to
        // use a technique from the book, you can.
    } // end choosePivot

    /******************************************************************************/
    private static int partition(Comparable[] theArray, int first, int last)
    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    // Partitions an array for quicksort.
    // Precondition: theArray[first..last] is an array;
    // first <= last.
    // Postcondition: Returns the index of the pivot element of
    // theArray[first..last]. Upon completion of the method,
    // this will be the index value lastS1 such that
    // S1 = theArray[first..lastS1-1] < pivot
    // theArray[lastS1] == pivot
    // S2 = theArray[lastS1+1..last] >= pivot
    // Calls: choosePivot.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    // tempItem is used to swap elements in the array
    {
        Comparable tempItem;
        // place pivot in theArray[first]
        choosePivot(theArray, first, last);
        Comparable pivot = theArray[first]; // reference pivot
        // initially, everything but pivot is in unknown
        int lastS1 = first; // index of last item in S1
        // move one item at a time until unknown region is empty
        for (int firstUnknown = first + 1; firstUnknown <= last; ++firstUnknown) {
            // Invariant: theArray[first+1..lastS1] < pivot
            // move item from unknown to proper region
            if (theArray[firstUnknown].compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                // item from unknown belongs in S1
                ++lastS1;
                tempItem = theArray[firstUnknown];
                theArray[firstUnknown] = theArray[lastS1];
                theArray[lastS1] = tempItem;
                comparisonCounter2++;
            } // end if
            // else item from unknown belongs in S2
        } // end for
        // place pivot in proper position and mark its location
        tempItem = theArray[first];
        theArray[first] = theArray[lastS1];
        theArray[lastS1] = tempItem;


        return lastS1;


    } // end partition

  /***********************************************************************/
    public static void quickSort(Comparable[] theArray, int first, int last) {
        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        // Sorts the items in an array into ascending order.
        // Precondition: theArray[first..last] is an array.
        // Postcondition: theArray[first..last] is sorted.
        // Calls: partition.
        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        int pivotIndex;
        if (first < last) {
            // create the partition: S1, Pivot, S2
            pivotIndex = partition(theArray, first, last);
            // sort regions S1 and S2
            quickSort(theArray, first, pivotIndex - 1);
            quickSort(theArray, pivotIndex + 1, last);
        } // end if
    } // end quickSort
} // end SortsClass
```

To replicate the problem, Run the SortsMain class, enter the array size, and which algorithm. The number of comparisons will print but are obviously wrong.

The loop counter's, named comparisonCounter and comparisonCounter2 are found in the SortsClass class. Everything sorts correctly, but the counter is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int firstUnknown = first + 1; firstUnknown <= last; ++firstUnknown) {
    if (theArray[firstUnknown].compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
        ++lastS1;
        tempItem = theArray[firstUnknown];
        theArray[firstUnknown] = theArray[lastS1];
        theArray[lastS1] = tempItem;
    } 
    comparisonCounter2++;  //move outside of if statement
    System.out.println(comparisonCounter2);
}
```

Output

```
Enter size of Array: 
3
Size of Array is: 3
Unsorted array: 
210357065, 1990514425, 960664583, Press 1 to use Bubble Sort
Press 2 to use Quick Sort
2
1
2
3
[210357065, 960664583, 1990514425]
```

Comment: How would i print out the value of the counter to System.in without getting caught in the recursive loop?

Comment: @ejk23 Not exactly sure what you mean.   I edited the answer to include a print statement.  Does this satisfy your requirements?

Comment: it does but it should only have 1 output (the number of comparisons). instead, it prints, for example 2,1,2,3

Comment: Two is actually the number of which algorithm is chosen.

Comment: right, but the System.out.print statement prints 2,1,2,3 as the number of comparisons

Comment: No, the first 2 is not printed out.  It is entered in the console.  But you are right it does get caught recursively and prints out.